# Finding minimizing probability density function

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-distributions, optimization

> Given probability density function $q$, find probability density function $p$ such that the following functional is minimized. $$  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{p(x)}{q^2(x)} \,{\rm d}x $$

---

I guess when $p=q$, it has the minimum, but I cannot prove it :( Although the $q$ and $p$ are all binary classification in our origin problem, I want to know the general case, similar to minimizing [Kullback–Leibler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) divergence

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p(x)\ln\left(\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}\right) \,{\rm  d} x$$ when $p=q$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: What is the support of $q$?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I guess that, as a start, we can suppose q to be with infinite support and "well behaved" (whatever it means :) ), e.g. a Gaussian density. Formalize the variational space for $p$ for me is also of interest (I did not do it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So told another way you want to minimize over some probability $p$:

$$F[p]=E_{X\sim p}[1/q^2(X)]$$

Notice that you can choose in this setting $p$ assigning higher or lower probability to different values of $x$. The question now can be read as: to what $x$ values do we want to assign higher/lower probability?

Make now the simplifying assumption that $q(x)$ is smooth and has a global maximum $q_{max}$, attained at a point $x_{max}$, so that $1/q^2(x)$ has a global minimum at the same $x_{max}$. Than you can choose $p(x)=\delta(x-x_{max})$ as your $p$, attaining:

$$F[\delta(x-x_{max})]=E_{X\sim \delta(x-x_{max})}[1/q^2(X)]=1/q^2_{max}$$

any other choice of $p$ would lead to the r.v. $1/q^2(X)$ to obtain values higher than $1/q^2_{max}$ for some point in the probability space, and therefore the expectation value would rise w.r.t this minimum.

I think the argument can be made rigorous by definining carefully all domains/codomains all the functions into play.

Comment: Thank you so much for you clear explanation. It inspires me a lot !

Comment: You are welcome. Let's wait if also others confirm the reasonings :)